# How to remove an object from the controller when an Ember.Checkbox is checked

Tags: ember.js

Currently I'm playing with the latest ember.js release and I'm building a simple "add username / remove username" hello world app. So far I can add a user (with the controller method below). I also have a checkbox in the html that when clicked should remove the user but ... right now I can only get the bool value of the checkbox to pass off. Instead I need the username to look it up and remove it from the controller content.

How can I re-do the html / view code below so that I can pass off the actual username instead of the bool value?

Thank you in advance!

```
    PersonApp.ModifyPersonCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
      change: function(event) {
        PersonApp.personController.removePerson(this.$().val());                                     
      },
    });

    PersonApp.personController = Em.ArrayProxy.create({
      content: [],

      createPerson: function(username) {
        var person = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: username });
        this.pushObject(person);
      },

      removePerson: function(username) {
        person = this.content.findProperty('username', username);
        this.removeObject(person);
      }

    });
```

the basic html below shows how my checkedBinding is wired up

```
<ul>
  {{#each PersonApp.personController}}
    <li {{bindAttr class="isActive"}}>
      <label>                                                                              
        {{view PersonApp.ModifyPersonCheckbox checkedBinding="isActive"}}
        {{username}}
      </label> 
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final solution looks like the below (notice the contentBinding="this" addition to the markup)

```
    PersonApp.ModifyPersonCheckbox = Em.Checkbox.extend({
      content: null,
      change: function(event) {
        PersonApp.personController.removePerson(this.content);                                     
      },
    });

    PersonApp.personController = Em.ArrayProxy.create({
      content: [],

      createPerson: function(username) {
        var person = PersonApp.Person.create({ username: username });
        this.pushObject(person);
      },

      removePerson: function(person) {
        this.removeObject(person);
      }

    });

<ul>
  {{#each PersonApp.personController}}
    <li {{bindAttr class="isActive"}}>
      <label>                                                                              
        {{view PersonApp.ModifyPersonCheckbox contentBinding="this" checkedBinding="isActive"}}
        {{username}}
      </label> 
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set the content on the view showing the checkbox so that when the event is triggered, the context is passed.  I believe this will work:

```
{{view PersonApp.ModifyPersonCheckbox contentBinding="parentView.content" checkedBinding="isActive"}}
```

Then, the event variable in the change function will have a context variable containing the record associated with that checkbox. Then you won't even need to search for it in the controller.  You can also just bind the username, but this way is cleaner.